# Why currying function works different from normal function in javascript for this case?

Tags: javascript, currying

I created a generator.
to run the code,

The final part is written in this way.

```
const genratorAnimation = gen(); 

let result = genratorAnimation.next();
genratorAnimation.next();

let interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(!result.done) {
     genratorAnimation.next();
   }
   else {
    clearInterval(interval)
   }
}, 50);
```

I tried to run this using non-currying function like.

```
let result = gen().next();
gen().next();

let interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(!result.done) {
    gen().next();
   }
   else {
    clearInterval(interval)
   }
}, 50);
```

However, it doesn't run the code properly. Why is that?
After reading postings here and other sources, the explanation seems like 
currying function is just another way of representing functions to me.

But this time, I realized that it's not it has a huge difference. 
Can anyone let me know the difference?

Comment: In this code, this code uses 
svg.node() to show circles.
Normally, to draw circles, I just needed to do svg.append(circles)....
without entering svg.node() however, this code uses svg.node().




I think this has also very strong correlation with currying function.

Please help. Since stack overflow doesn't allow me to add more codes here, I will add the original code as a comment. It would be grateful if you have a look.

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (i % 5 === 0) yield svg.node();
            const cx = x(values[i]); // x(values[i]);->what is this?
            const cy = height - margin.bottom - dodge(cx) - radius - 1;

            svg
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", cx)
                .attr("cy", -400)
                .attr("r", radius)
                .attr("fill", "red")
        }

        yield svg.node();

Comment: What **exactly** does "doesn't run the code properly" mean?

Comment: You are constantly creating multiple generators. Each time you call `.next()` you will get the first item. While this looks like currying it is not. Generators are actually continuations

Comment: you meant, genratorAnimation.next() and gen().next() are different? generatorAnimation = gen() but why it's different???

Comment: No, I mean each time you call `gen()` it returns a continuation object. It has nothing to do with currying. It's like `var a = new Array(1,2,3), var b = new Array(4,5,6)` -- `a` and `b` are two different variables. Similarly `generatorAnimation = gen()` and `generatorAnimation2 = gen()` create two different variables. In your second code you create an infinite amount of continuation object each time you call `gen()`. I stress again, this has nothing to do with currying. This is more like the `new` operator in object-oriented programming

Comment: Got ya Understood!!! Thank you so much!!! by setting the get() generator as a varialbe, the generator is called only once. and in the following line, it keeps doing next() to the generator I called first. wow!!! thank you thank you.

Comment: If possible, can you by chance have a look for the svg.node() question I wrote below? I'm wondering if it has a similar logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call `gen()` you return a new `Generator` so you constantly reinitialize it.
That's why your code doesn't work when using the second version.

Your example could be summarized with this:

```js
const add = function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () { counter += 1; return counter; }
};

const count = add();

// Works
console.log('Works');
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());

//Doesn't work
console.log('Doesn\'t work');
console.log(add()());
console.log(add()());
console.log(add()());
```

Comment: So if I set the function as a variable, it doesn't call the function again. it just let the function keep going. 

Can you let me know why the code is using svg.node() by chance?
Because to draw something I just needed to svg.append().attr() ...etc etc.

However, in the code,

Comment: To generate balls here, it is using svg.node() not just by adding circels on the svg.